# Function before hide() finishes

Tags: jquery

```
container.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, function() {
            $('#go-back').show();
        });
```

I want to trigger a function on start of this event. `$('#go-back').show();` triggers once it's finished, and that is fine, but I want to run a new function when this HIDE() event starts. Can't find anything on the web.

Comment: But that's just executing the code immediately after the closing `});`.  Have you tried that already?

Comment: m8, thanks. My head wasn't working clearly yesterday :)